# Sails data from service to controller

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm starting with sails js and node more generally .

I'm trying to use the regular way of implementing services in sails to pass data in my controller.

for example, I've a dashboard view, called dashboard.ejs

my view is correctly routed and everything.

But the regular ways of passing data from service wasn't working at all, and I ended up with that to make it work, which seems to be very unappropriate:

my CountService.js:

```
module.exports = {

RoomCount: function(req, res, cb, tab)
{
Room.count().exec(function(err, roomfound){
    tab.push(roomfound);
    cb(req, res, tab);
});
},
VenteCount: function(req, res, cb, tab)
{
Vente.count().exec(function(err, ventefound){
    tab.push(ventefound);
    cb(req, res, tab);
});
},
LotCount: function(req, res, cb, tab)
{
Lot.count().exec(function(err, lotfound){
    tab.push(lotfound);
    cb(req, res, tab);
});
}
};
```

My DashboardController.js

```
module.exports = {


dashboard: function(req, res, next)
{
var tab = []
var end_dashboard = function(req, res, tab){
    res.view('dashboard', {
            roomCount: tab[0],
            venteCount: tab[1],
    lotCount: tab[2]
        });
};
var callbacklot = function(req, res, tab){
    end_dashboard(req, res, tab);
};
var callbackvente = function(req, res, tab){
    CountService.LotCount(req, res, callbacklot, tab);
};
var callbackroom = function(req, res, tab){
    CountService.VenteCount(req, res, callbackvente, tab);
};
CountService.RoomCount(req, res, callbackroom, tab);
},
};
```

And then I can call the VenteCount etc values in my view ejs

The regular way was giving a value = undefined

I think I was wrong in the res() or next() part so I ended like that but it makes the service thing very complicated...

Thanks a lot for your help